# Can particles change once they reach the end of their life?

Tags: particles

I created a simple particle effect using a red block, some turbulence and a white circle.

I was wondering if there was some way to have the circles pop when they reach the end of their lifetime?

[image]

The included gif was mostly rendered in blender, with the short popping animation added in post to demonstrate the effect I'm looking for. So far I haven't found a way to change significant details of particles when they reach the end of their life.

I know it's a complicated question, but any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: just give them a image sequence as material and set the frames to the according to the lifetime of your particles.

Comment: if you wanna have random lifetime, you could achieve the same effect with geometry nodes.

Comment: @Chris thanks for the advice. I do like having a random lifetime. Do you know a geometry nodes setup I might be able to use?

Comment: maybe this one https://youtu.be/EkMOm4dDYSw - but it's Simulation Nodes, Blender 3.6